# How to check a checkmenuitem in Sencha Test

Tags: extjs, sencha-test, sencha-test-2.1

**Using Sencha Test 2.1**

So I'm trying to check a checkboxmenuitem which is an item in a button menu.

I can reference it but the method check is not availble for it:

```
component.gotoButton('[text=See]').gotoCheckBox('menucheckitem[text=All]').check();
```

*-calling check on a ST.future.CheckBox does work but this is a checkboxmenuitem*

Comment: I did not find a `menucheckitem` on Sencha Touch 2.1 or Sencha Test docs. Where did you get that from?

Comment: Sorry I meant to add sencha-test-2.1 tag not sencha touch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a menucheckitem, the checkbox isn't an instance of Ext.form.field.CheckBox, so you'd want to retrieve the ST.Element future from the menuitem future, and then perform a click() on it.

For example, using this url: http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/examples/kitchensink/?classic#toolbar-menus

```
ST.button('button[text="Button w/ Menu"]') // button future
  .expand() // expand to reveal menu
  .gotoComponent('menuitem[text="I like Ext"]') // menuitem future
  .down('>> .x-menu-item-checkbox') // use down() to get Element future
  .click(); // execute click on Element future
```

If you want to be less verbose, you could also do something like this directly from the Button future:

```
ST.button('button[text="Button w/ Menu"]')
  .expand()
  .down('menu => .x-menu-item-checkbox') // use composite query to locate element
  .click();
```

Comment: Yeah I was going down that path as well (click event) ... the only problem is that this menucheckitem could be already checked and with a click I could be checking it or unchecking it.  I can probably add some of the classes to the selector in addition to the text but this would be fragil when we do a Ext framework upgrade.

Comment: Well, another possible option would be to create your own component future. We don't really have much in terms of documentation for creating your own, and it's not safe from conflicts with future implementations, but it should work. This is pretty untested, but a simple case seems to work:

https://gist.github.com/joelwatson/2e5664ac6695de3e6259d3a26dac7a46

Comment: Oh, interesting! Will take a look at that, thanks Joel.